# Summations of $\frac{1}{n^p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, recreational-mathematics

I wasn't able to find any information on this, so I'm just curious and am asking here.

We know the summation (n sums from 1 to infinity) of $\frac{1}{n^2}$, $\frac{1}{n^4}$, and I'm sure finding $\frac{1}{n^k}$ where k is a multiple of 2 shouldn't be an issue.

My question is, do we know the value of $\frac{1}{n^p}$ for any prime p? As far as I know, we know approximately what $\frac{1}{n^3}$ sums to but we don't have a precise value as we do, for instance, for $\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Again, I'm just curious, and would love to learn more.

Comment: that's the zeta function

Comment: Nope. In fact, if we figured out a value of even just $\zeta(3) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^3$, it would be news-worthy, at least in the mathematics community. None of the odd inputs (greater than $3$), and thus all odd primes, to the zeta function have no known exact value

Comment: You might be interested in this page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: @EeveeTrainer wow that's...surprising, actually. It seems like such a simple think to investigate. That said, there are many seemingly simple problems which evaded proof for long periods, so in hindsight, I suppose I'm not that surprised.

Comment: @Dasherman definitely helpful. Thanks for the link

Comment: @Adib0y360 Regarding this issue pragmatically, why do you believe that the number $\pi$, or the number $\log(2)$, or the number $\sin(1)$ is more satisfying to see in an expression than say $\zeta(3)$? Is it only because you have more experience using $\pi$, $\log(2)$, and $\sin(1)$?  Both $\zeta(3)$ and those aforementioned numbers are irrational.  So, why are some considered acceptable as "known" numbers while the other, $\zeta(3)$, is considered something more elusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Riemann zeta function, commonly given by $\zeta(s)$, can be written like this:
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^s}$$. It is known that $\zeta(1)$ is indeterminate, as $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}(\zeta(1+\epsilon))=\pm\infty$$
and that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. As it would seem, the solutions for most even $s$ can be expressed as $\frac{\pi^m}{n}$ ($m,n\in\Bbb{Z}$). However, $\zeta(s)$ for odd $s$ are not as easy to express. For example, probably the nicest way of representing $\zeta(3)$, a.k.a. Apéry's constant, is:
$$\zeta(3)=-\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1\frac{\log^3(1-t)^2}{t^3}dt$$
which is actually pretty neat. Except we can't actually express this integral unless we give it in terms of the zeta function. So, the closest we've got so far is approximation by numerical methods. There are other functions capable of representing values for odd $s$, but that's only because the functions were defined for cases like this. Hope this helps.

Comment: In fact, for $s=2n,n \in \Bbb Z^+$, there is a known closed form:

$$\zeta (2n)=(-1)^{{n+1}}{\frac  {B_{{2n}}(2\pi )^{{2n}}}{2(2n)!}}\!$$

where $B_k$ denote the Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer You learn something new everyday :)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer "Closed form" is debatable. In some sense, without resorting to an integral or recursion, maybe the best you can do for $B_k$ is a double finite summation. But it immediately tells us that $\zeta(2n)$ is a rational multiple of the appropriate power of $\pi$.

Comment: The values of $\zeta(2 n)$ were all determined by Euler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned by the patrial sums$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^s}=H_n^{(s)}$$ where appear the generalized harmonic numbers.

Usig their asymptotics, we have
$$S_n=n^{-s} \left(\frac{n}{1-s}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{12 n}+\frac{s (s+1) (s+2)}{720
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\right)+\zeta (s)$$

Just for the fun of it, use it for $s=\pi$ and $n=10$. The "exact" value is $1.1732134857$ while the above truncated expression would give $1.1732134864$